# Retrieving React state value via dynamic variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a simple rgba selector which allows users to toggle the individual values via the arrow-up and arrow-down keys. Below is a snippet of my code.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
   red: 0,
   green: 200,
   blue: 0,
   opacity: 1,
};
this.handleValueChange = this.handleValueChange.bind(this);
this.handleArrowKeysInput = this.handleArrowKeysInput.bind(this);

// for using up and down arrows to adjust the values
    handleArrowKeysInput = e => {
    const keyPressed = e.keyCode;
    let {id} = e.target;
    console.log(id); //returns red OR green OR blue
    console.log(this.state.id);

    // if up button is pressed
    if(keyPressed === 38){
      // if value is already 255, stop increment
      if(this.state.green >= 255) return;
      console.log(`up button is pressed`);
      this.setState({[id]: this.state.id + 1});
    }

    // if down button is pressed 
    else if(keyPressed === 40){
      // if value is already 0, stop decrement
      if(this.state.id <= 0) return;
      console.log(`down button is pressed`);
      this.setState({[id]: this.state.id - 1});
    }
  }
```

`<input value={this.state.red} type="text" id="red" onChange=
  {this.handleValueChange} onKeyDown={this.handleArrowKeysInput}/>`

`console.log(id)` returns the desired value red or green or blue.

However when i tried to `console.log(this.state.id)`. It shows `undefined`.

Why is this so?

Comment: Are you giving a initial value to `id` when you are creating state values on `constructor`?

Comment: @bennygenel hi, i don't really understand your question. could you explain more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a bit confusing probably because its not a [Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but I try to give you some options to fix it.

There is no `id` value on you initial state construction.

**Example**

```
this.state = {
   red: 0,
   green: 200,
   blue: 0,
   opacity: 1,
   id: 0  // This should be here if you are going to use it
};
```

Secondly you are trying to add up 1 to a `undefined` value below;

```
this.setState({[id]: this.state.id + 1});
```

Because `this.state.id` is `undefined`, `this.state[id]` will be undefined too. But from what I understand from your code you are trying to set `red`, `green` and `blue` values, so your code should be like below;

```
this.setState({[id]: this.state[id] + 1});
```

Because you are trying to get a state value on the above code it is a better practice to use functional `setState`;

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({[id]: prevState[id] + 1}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because there is no 'id' property in your state object. Instead, you should set the state by first checking the value of id, and then for example if it is 'red', you can call `setState({red: this.state.red - 1})`.

Here is a more clear example of what I mean:

```
if(keyPressed === 38){
    switch (id) {
        case "red":
            if(this.state.red >= 255) return;
            this.setState({red: this.state.red + 1});
        break;
        case "green":
            if(this.state.green >= 255) return;
            this.setState({green: this.state.green + 1});
        break;
        case "blue":
            if(this.state.blue >= 255) return;
            this.setState({blue: this.state.blue + 1});
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm in my case, `console.log(id)` returns e.g red. hence i am trying to access the state via `this.state.id`. Question is how can i do that? what should be the correct syntax. i am implementing it this way to avoid repeating the `handleArrowKeysInput()` code

Comment: thank you for your answer @sme. i was looking for a method to avoid repeating the statements though

Comment: No problem, yeah I agree its best to avoid repeating statements, so no worries

Answer (score 0):

Mistake that you are doing is:

You are updating the state properties `red`, `green` and `blue` by the key `id` (dynamic value), and accessing the state value by `this.state.id`, and `id` property doesn't exist in state.

To get the value from state using id, use this:

```
console.log(this.state[id]);
```

**Full code:**

```
handleArrowKeysInput = e => {
    const keyPressed = e.keyCode;
    let {id} = e.target;

    if(keyPressed === 38){
        if(this.state.green >= 255) return;
        this.setState(prevState => ({[id]: prevState[id] + 1}));
    }

    else if(keyPressed === 40){
        if(this.state[id] <= 0) return;
        this.setState(prevState => ({[id]: prevState[id] - 1}));
    }
}
```

Check this snippet:

```js
let state = {
  red: 1,
  green: 2,
  blue: 3
}

let id = 'red';

console.log('value of red id = ', state[id]);
console.log('state.id will be "undefined" = ', state.id);
```